# Which method of checking to see if a NSDictionary contains a particular key is faster?

Tags: cocoa, performance, nsdictionary

I can test for the presence of a key in an NSDictionary in two ways:

```
BOOL containsKey = [[dictionary allKeys] containsObject:foo];

BOOL containsKey = ([dictionary objectForKey:foo] != nil);
```

which method is faster, and why?

Comment: "Please show your work?" You've got the same tools we do.  You should try profiling the different code if you want to know the answer to something like this.

Comment: Daniel is absolutely correct, this was a very lazy way of getting the answer to an easy to test question. But I got some really good answer and some real performance results, so thanks everyone for letting me be a little lazy.

Comment: I get that people are a little put out by the "Please show your work" line in the question above, but I thought that the point of stack overflow is to have answers to all sorts of basic questions, no?

So, to clarify, I didn't ask this because I don't know the answer, couldn't find out myself, or to be a rude jerk. Rather, because the answer is not immediately obvious unless you're familiar with the Foundation collections it seemed like a good question and answer to have available.

Comment: This question has been the cause of more than several flags from our community. I've made a minor edit to your question, please consider keeping it (or revising my edit to be anything but what it was originally).

Comment: I totally didn't realize I could edit the question after the fact. /facepalm

Comment: Is there a difference between having a key = nil and not having the key at all?

Comment: FYI you might gain a little speed using `CFDictionaryContainsKey ((__bridge CFDictionaryRef) (dictionary), foo);`

Answer (score 68, accepted):

A hash lookup should be faster in general than going over all the dictionary keys, creating an array from them (memory allocation is relatively expensive) and then searching the array (which can't even be a binary search since the array is not sorted).

For the sake of science, though, I made two executables that just execute each style 1 million times and timed them.

With allKeys:

```
real    0m4.185s
user    0m3.890s
sys     0m0.252s
```

With objectForKey:

```
real    0m0.396s
user    0m0.189s
sys     0m0.029s
```

Obviously, various factors can influence this — size of the dictionary, caching the allKeys return value, etc. I wouldn't expect there to be a case in which the array search is faster than the dictionary lookup, though.

Comment: Chuck, can you test using valueForKey with a dictionary in a dictionary? I think this would be most useful in addition to knowing that objectForKey performs faster. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

I don't see how asking for the allKeys array could possibly be faster, otherwise NSDictionary would at least do the equivalent internally.

EDIT: I suppose that you could construct a case where the `allKeys` method would be faster - by taking a long time in your key's `hash` method, but not in your `isEqual:` method, for example. And you could also swap in a crazy implementation for `NSDictionary` in which they are swapped, too (since `NSDictionary` is abstract.)

Comment: Agreed. Asking for allKeys is going to give you an NSArray which containsObject must then iteratively search looking for foo. objectForKey, on the other hand, will use a hash to compute the location of foo in the dictionary so that foo's existence can be determined directly.

Answer (score 2):

When thinking about performance questions like this, keep in mind that the Foundation data classes swap out their underlying data structures depending on how many objects you store in them. For example, I think a small NSArray actually uses a hash table for storage until it reaches a certain size.

Comment: Isn't it more likely to be the other way round where a hash table becomes more beneficial? Testing 10 or so objects for equality is trivial. Have several thousand objects though, and a hash table becomes a clear win.

Comment: You could very well be right, I remember someone wrote an article (along with benchmarks) about this some time ago, but I haven't given it much thought since then.

Comment: http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/array.html would be the post you are thinking of